# org-mode paragraph alignment issue

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm facing an issue with paragraph alignment after a list item. See the bitmap that makes it more clear:

**Heading**

First line

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2

  Second line is aligned with the list above. I did used two blank-lines to signify the end of list.

[Org-Mode Paragraph Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOPBz.png)

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with org-mode: it's how LaTeX indents paragraphs after the first one (at least in the default styles); it does not happen when exporting to e.g., HTML.

For LaTeX, you can set the indent to 0 if you want all paragraphs to start at the left margin, by adding this to the top of your org file:

```
#+LATEX: \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```